# How do I pull data from IF statement and add to another cell formula?

Tags: excel, if-statement, sum

This is probably something simple but I cant figure it out. I need to pull the results from one cell (C22) that has this formula:

=IF(I14=1, "177", IF(I14=2, "177", IF(I14=3, "177", IF(I14=4, "184", IF(I14=5, "215", IF(I14=6, "246", IF(I14>7, "246")))))))

and add to another cells totals.  The other cell is a simple (k12) =SUM(C13:C21).  If I do something like =SUM(C13:C21+C22), I get the total of c13:c21 **AND** the full total of all the amounts of the above IF formula (C22).  What I need is the total of c13:c21 plus the individual selection of the IF formula. Example, if I put 1, I need c13:c21 + 177.   If I put 4, I need c13:c21 + 184,  and so on.

How would I write this formula for cell K12 to give the totals of c13:c21 PLUS the individual selection of the C22 IF formula??

Comment: You can write the if formula much simpler: =CHOOSE(I14;177;177;177;184;215;246;246) It if there is a 4 in cell I14, it will choose 184

Answer (score 2):

I think below should work.

```
=SUM(C13:C21,C22)
```

When you will use `=SUM(C13:C21+C22)`, this means to each cell of range `C13:C22` will be added value of cell `C22`. Another option can be `=SUM(C13:C21)+C22` but you do not need this as you can add multiple cell range to `SUM()` function.